# Launch the same script several times

Tags: python

I try to launch the same script several times on python.

I have finished my script but I don't know how to launch my script several times.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! The `for` loop may helps you : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make a shell command if you have access to a Unix-Shell. Something like this might work:

```bash
number_of_times=5
for i in $(seq 1 $number_of_times); do 
  # Your command here:
  python3 main.py
done
```

Assuming you're using `python3` and some script `main.py`